# Date.ValueOf not accepting null

Tags: apex

```
String str = null;
Date d = Date.valueOf(str);
```

I am getting the following error when running the above snippet in Anon Apex.

```
Line: 2, Column: 1
System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.
```

This is quite strange.

I have a field that contains string data and my target field is of Date Datatype as such I am using `Date.ValueOf` to convert it.

The quirk here is that the string field may also be null.

My code is failing because `Date.ValueOf()` does not accept null value as its input parameter.

What I hoped was that upon seeing a null value in the parameter, the `Date.ValueOf()` will also return a null value.

Can anyone tell me what should I do here ?

What is the null equivalent for a date in Salesforce ?

Comment: Why not a simple null check before performing your necessary operations

Comment: I use the conversion in assignment operation for object initialization..something like this  new Obj( Date_Value = Date.ValueOf(String) );

Comment: Not sure how can I do a null check in my case..see my prev comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not

```
Date d = String.isBlank(str)
          ? null
          : Date.valueOf(str);
```

Comment: beat me to it :)