# Why does valueOf not work with NULLs sometimes?

Tags: apex

This question is not about how to solve the problem but rather why it is there in the first place.

So consider these four lines:

```
Object myString;
Object myDecimal;

System.debug(String.valueOf(myString));
System.debug(Decimal.valueOf((String) myDecimal));
```

The first statement will work but the second statement will not and I'm really wondering why? I mean - converting a null value to a different type shouldn't be a problem, right? It's still null after all.

Of course I could easily fix this by having a null check in place:

```
myDecimal == null ? myDecimal : Decimal.valueOf(myDecimal);
```

While this will work - I would have to add this to every `valueOf` with a null input would also yield a bulk output.

Any ideas?

See also: [Date.ValueOf not accepting null](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117171/date-valueof-not-accepting-null)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a design choice:

- The author of the `String.valueOf` chose to allow a `null` argument (presumably generating the string 'null').
- The author of `Decimal.valueOf` chose to report a `null` argument as an error; I would guess the thinking there was better to "fail fast" rather than propagate the `null`.

To avoid lots of `null` checks, design your code to avoid `null` values by e.g. initializing variables where they are declared. If a value of `null` has to be allowed, address that in one place only by e.g. not calling other code that requires a non-`null` value.

See e.g. [10 Tips to Handle Null Effectively](https://dzone.com/articles/10-tips-to-handle-null-effectively); a couple of these are specific to Java but most apply to Apex.

Comment: The problem is, Null can be returned by SOQL, even if you know that the field type is Decimal. Because of this, you need to write unnecessary checks in all these places…

like this: `if (a.Length_Of_Service__c == Null || a.Length_Of_Service__c == 0)`

Comment: After coming back to this after some years I just wanted to point out that `String.valueOf` does not generate the string 'null' but rather just returns the null-string that was passed. This also fails for integers and I guess other types as well - seems like string is the only one that returns `null`.